# Why would and when do Qubits collapse into one state upon observation?

Tags: quantum-computer, superposition

Something like an electron would act like a particle upon observation because the high energy light waves interfere with it. But what about Qubits? Why do they collapse into one state? And when do they collapse into one state, is it when they are rendered onto the screen? But why would that be the case bits/qubits are just an electrical voltage, which isn't being observed by high energy light waves so why should it become 1 state?

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, a qubit is a quantum system having two distinguishable states. The qubit can be implemented in many ways - electron spin, photon polarization, ions spin, quasiparticles called anyons ("transitional" entities between fermions and bosons, so far only theory) etc.

As any quantum system, when the qubit is measured, it collapses into one of possible states based on wave function describing the qubit.

Comment: Arent anyons only on 2 dimensional spaces?

Comment: @Octavylon: It is true, however, they can be prepared in two dimensional structures in 3D. See this link for more info: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11399/topological-quantum-computer-and-two-dimensional-materials